# TFS 2013: Why can't I create charts for "tag" based queries?

Tags: charts, azure-devops

I have a simple query that lists out workitems marked with a certain "tag." When I try to create an Area chart for this query, I get the following error:

[image: TFS chart error]

Is this controlled by my TFS admin? If not, why aren't charts based on "tag" field supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a feature request submitted for this on MS User Voice, refer to this link for details: [Add trend chart support for tag-based queries](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7136882-add-trend-chart-support-for-tag-based-queries).

By the way, this feature is available in TFS2015, you can upgrade your TFS version if you do want this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it's because tags aren't actual work item fields, but instead are metadata that can be attached to work items at any time.